# Spring Boot React AWS What is a good strategy to deploy a Spring Boot Microservices + React multi-tenant App to AWS?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, microservices, multi-tenant

We are building a SaaS App with Spring Boot based microservices as the backend, and a ReactJS front end.

For Multi Tenancy, we're currently following the `discriminator` strategy, where each HTTP request comes with a header called `TENANT-ID` that bears the ID of the current tenant, and the Spring JPA layer takes care of the data isolation.

We have deployed this App into AWS for testing purposes, and have validated the multi tenancy approach from the database and backend side.

However, one flip side to this is, that in our React UI, we are forcing a user to enter his Login ID, Password **and the Tenant ID** in the login form, so that we can resolve the current tenant.

We wish to change this approach like this:
When a customer is onboarded, we want to create a URL like this: **https://tenant1.myapp.com** or **https://tenant2.myapp.com** and so on, and have the API gateway read this URL and extract the Tenant ID out of it, and pass it to downstream microservices.

So below is my architecture:

1. We have one docker container for the React Frontend (just the frontend, with no backend)
2. One Docker container each for Eureka and Spring Cloud gateway
3. One docker container each for all my microservices, ELK stack, etc.

My questions are as follows:

1. In AWS, how can we programmatically create a new sub-domain (like tenant1.myapp.com or tenant2.myapp.com) when a tenant is onboarded?
2. Should we have one instance of our React App and link all the tenant sub domains to it (is it really possible), or should we create an EC2 instance for each tenant and link the sub domain to it?
3. How do we expose end user APIs?

If my question appears vague, please suggest edits so that I can give more specific information. As I said, we're totally new to this area, and any direction will surely help us go a long way.

Thanks,
Sriram

Comment: AWS Route 53 enables you to handle wildcard subdomains https://aws.amazon.com/route53/faqs/#:~:text=A%20wildcard%20entry%20is%20a,Q.

Comment: you should be having a single instance of react app across all tenants. A single code base for all tenants is a better option. You should be having some strategy to spin out new clusters if load is high for the UI.

Comment: All you API's should be accepting a tenant-id header that makes your API tenant aware and handle DB isolation etc. If these are not clear, you can provide a little more detail on your ask here